# Excessive Water Running Alert (Left the Hose On)

Tags: water, pump, well-pump, water-tank

We are designing a rain water collection system involving 27,500 gallons of tank storage that will serve to replace a dried up well for the whole house needs.

Accidentally leaving a hose running happens (especially with kids :).  We are looking for a monitoring device/system that will alert if the tank pumps are running excessively (more than the normal flushing of toilets and doing laundry and filling horse troughs).  It would be a shame to accidentally empty those tanks of precious New Mexico rainwater.

Any ideas or thoughts?

Thank you,

Kevin

Comment: What comes to my mind is a modification to a RV's or mobile homes water holding tank system. As I recall there is a sending unit (just like automobiles fuel sending devices) that depending on the position of its float will send different amounts of voltage to a gauge (or LED's) According to the amount will deflect a gauge (or turn on LED's).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for is a remote water level monitoring system. It is all up to cost on how elaborate of a system you want. Here is the google [search](https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl&rct=j#newwindow=1&q=water%20level%20monitoring%20system).

Comment: Thanks.  I have been googling but obviously not using the right terms (silly me).  One system that does look promising is http://leakdefensesystem.com/commercial-users/  Water flow monitor that can be set to alarm and even cut-off the flow after a pre-determined amount of constant flow.

Comment: Sounds like you found what you were looking for. I learned to do searches  from my wife, I would try to put to much information and would get nothing. She told me to try to keep it simple, and it works most of the time.

Answer (score 0):

How about a dedicated hose valve were the only way that water would flow is if constant hand pressure is applied? Some kind of bulbous rubber bladder that when pressure was applied an internal gate or washer opened an inlet to allow water flow. Something similar to the 'wieners' you shove into a clogged pipe with the hose attached. Than even if a kid forgets to turn the water off it won't matter. Just let go and the valve closes. If there isn't one in the consumer market I'll make one! Patent Pending.

Comment: Thanks but this is the main supply for the whole house.  Honey!  Could you hold this valve open so I can take my shower!  :)

Comment: My bad. I was  seeing the problem as a 'landscape irrigation'  issue.